# Удаление дубликатов с максимальным значением идентификатора

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как написать запрос, для удаления дубликатов? Должны остаться уникальные записи с минимальным идентификатором.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачу можно решить через `CTE` и использование функции `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE(N) AS
(
 SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [столбец 1], [столбец 2], [столбец N] ORDER BY id ASC)
 FROM [таблица]
)
DELETE CTE WHERE N>1;
```

Где:

- `[столбец 1], [столбец 2], [столбец N]` — перечень столбцов по которым определяются уникальные записи;
- `id` — идентификатор в вашей таблице;
- `[таблица]` — таблица из которой производите удаление.

Comment: А если будет обратная ситуация, удалить с минимальным индификатоорм, можно ли как-то этот запрос переделать

Comment: Надо сменить порядок сортировки `id`